# Does `That's very sweet of you` in the US sound like `That's very sweef you`?

Tags: american-english

Does `That's very sweet of you`  in the US sound like `That's very sweef you`?
the `of` is only speak `f` and link with `swee`

Comment: [**Does x in the US sound** like y]= question form.

Comment: @Lambie thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are hearing is just an example of "connected speech". When anyone speaks in their native language they do not stop after each word, but one word naturally runs into the next. To a British English speaker like myself, many American pronunciations of the letter 'T' sound more like a 'D'. As it is easier for a 'D' sound to merge with the 'F' sound in "of", you are probably noticing this more with American accents that with British.

Comment: thanks @Astralbee

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I'd also argue that it's possible the the T (alveolar tap in American English, what you called a D) may wind up not being sounded at all in quick speech, as the tongue may not reach the roof of the mouth. Alternatively, some other accents would have a glottal stop for the T, which can also wind up being omitted in quick continuous speech

Comment: FWIW, in my corrupted American accent (U.S. upbringing, 33 years there, 19 years since in the UK) I pronounce it "That's very swee dove view."

Comment: I strongly disagree. Sweet of you is not connected by changing the t sound to an f sound, as in sweef. It would be: sweeduv (more US) or sweetuv (more British) for sweet of you. Your answer is too technical for a learner...

Comment: @Lambie Sorry you disagree so strongly, but I'm not sure you've understood my answer correctly. I don't believe I said that the two words are modified deliberately so that they can be connected. Connected speech is something that all natives use, no matter what their accent or dialect. What I have said - in one of my shortest answers ever, so I'm not sure how it is too technical - is that the typical American pronunciation of this phrase may blur the two words more than the typical British pronunciation, and I stand by my answer.

Comment: My issue is not about connected speech. Of course, there is connected speech. **It is about your characterization of it**. There are two possibilities here: sueduv [D] you and sweetuv [T] you (alveolar tap).

Comment: @Lambie - You're absolutely right, but could benefit from listing _other_ values of "T". There's 1. the plain glottal stop like in "kettle", 2. a mixture of the glottal stop and closing/nonplosive "T" at the ends of words like _sweet_ (which is what I think our OP heard), and the nasal value as in "often" (although it's becoming worn down to just "offen" these days).

Answer (score 2):

Somebody has a speech impediment.  Add a regional accent and it changes even more.

The normal speech would sound like that is sweetuv you with the t clearly enunciated but the of being run into the preceeding word not with the t and o being elided.

Comment: Yes, and it can also sound like: sweeduv.

Comment: thanks sharing. @joe sixpak

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the "f" with a "v," then yes, kind of. By "kind of," I mean that it's definitely possible, but it's probably not common, so you should not think of it as the normal US English pronunciation.

I assume that you mean "sweev you" (since "of" ends in a /v/ sound). It wouldn't be weird if an American English speaker didn't pronounce the final consonant in "sweet" and said something that sounds like "swEE-uv-you," with three syllables. (In the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA), this would be spelled [swi-ʌv-ju].) And then the first two syllables could be somewhat blurred together so that it sounds almost like one syllable, "sweev" (IPA: [swiv]).

More commonly, though, it'll sound like "swEE-duv-you". In American English, /t/ often turns into what's called an alveolar flap, something that sounds an awful lot like /d/ (IPA: [swi-ɾʌv-ju]).